# Rails 5 Chat With MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I keep seeing on different tutorials stating that in order to use Rails 5 ActionCable for chat you must use a PostgreSQL database. This tutorial here makes this claim also.

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/creating-a-chat-using-rails-action-cable

I'm running Rails 5 with MySQL and cannot swap over to a PostgreSQL database due to technical requirements. Has anyone found any alternatives for this? I haven't seen anything documented online about the issue.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://jameshuynh.com/2016/02/12/rails-5-real-time-web-app-with-action-cable/) and [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-5-actioncable-websockets) both seem to indicate you can use MySQL. I didn't [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=rails+actioncable+mysql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) any further than that, but it seems do-able.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: I've used ActionCable with MySQL. It makes use of web sockets which should be independent of databases.